# wordpress is adding a second backslash when I use addslashes

Tags: plugin-development, json, sanitization

I don't know why but it seems like wordpress is adding a second backslash when I'm using the following functions:

```
addslashes($str_with_single_quotes)
addslashes(stripslashes($str_with_single_quotes));
esc_sql($str_with_single_quotes)
str_replace("'", "/'", $str_with_single_quotes)
```

What I'm doing is that I'm fetching data from different API's and then converting those data to a json string so I can access them later on:

```
$item_data = array(
    'item_title' => __(addslashes(stripslashes($item_name))),
    'product_review' => __(addslashes(stripslashes($product_review))),
    'freebase_text' => __(addslashes(stripslashes($freebase_result['text'])))
);

$data = json_encode($item_data);
```

It doesn't seem like the localization function (`__()`) is the one that's causing the problem since the problem is still there even I completely remove it.

I also tried `preg_replace_all` but I got a fatal error that the function wasn't recognize. I also tried using `str_replace`, `esc_sql`, and `str_replace` after the array was converted a json string but no luck.

I've run out of ideas on how to solve this problem. Simply using `json_encode` without processing the strings doesn't actually do anything and the single quotes are left unescaped.

Magic quotes are also disabled:

```
magic_quotes_gpc = Off
magic_quotes_runtime = Off
magic_quotes_sybase = Off
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code json_encode() function causes to add second backslash on the following line.

```
$data = json_encode($item_data);
```

Add the following code in place of above code so it will replace double backslashes with single backslash in data returned by json_encode function.

```
$data = str_replace("\\\'","\\'",json_encode($item_data ));
```

Visit following links for more information on json_encode function.

[json_encode function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

[json_encode function Predefined Constants](http://www.php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php)

Tell me whether it resolved your problem or i will find another solution for it.

Comment: thanks! this works. but the json string that it returned still doesn't have a valid format. If you don't mind please check the json string that I have in here: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/126688107/zencap/invalid_json.js